# 502 Bad Gateway after SSL installation on Nginx and Django

Tags: nginx, ssl, vps, django

I have a 502 error on my vps after I installed SSL certificate. 
systemctl status nginx.service:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-02-24 01:49:15 +03; 12min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 2393 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2395 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2396 (nginx)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 1012)
     Memory: 4.0M
        CPU: 102ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─2396 "nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;"
             └─2612 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

on error.log

```
2024/02/24 01:57:10 [crit] 2612#2612: *15 connect() to unix:/home/delta/site/delta-django/app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: , server: , request: "GET /old/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/delta/site/delta-django/app.sock:/old/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=1", host: "deltaozelders.com"
2024/02/24 01:57:11 [crit] 2612#2612: *18 connect() to unix:/home/delta/site/delta-django/app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: , server: , request: "GET /OLD/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/delta/site/delta-django/app.sock:/OLD/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=1", host: "deltaozelders.com"
2024/02/24 01:57:12 [crit] 2612#2612: *21 connect() to unix:/home/delta/site/delta-django/app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: , server: , request: "GET /wp-admin/install.php?step=1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/delta/site/delta-django/app.sock:/wp-admin/install.php?step=1", host: "deltaozelders.com"
2024/02/24 01:57:21 [crit] 2612#2612: *23 connect() to unix:/home/delta/site/delta-django/app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: , server: , request: "POST /Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/delta/site/delta-django/app.sock:/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml", host: ""
2024/02/24 02:00:10 [crit] 2612#2612: *27 connect() to unix:/home/delta/site/delta-django/app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: , server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/delta/site/delta-django/app.sock:/", host: "deltaozelders.com"
```

Nginx -t:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2024/02/24 01:53:53 [warn] 2745#2745: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2024/02/24 01:53:53 [emerg] 2745#2745: cannot load certificate key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/deltaozelders.com/privkey.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:8000000D:system library::Permission denied:calling fopen(/etc/letsencrypt/live/deltaozelders.com/privkey.pem, r) error:10080002:BIO routines::system lib)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: Your Django app isn't running or configured to create a socket in another place than `/home/delta/site/delta-django/app.sock`. You also need to run `nginx -t` as a `root` user.